# How can I adjust this short shell script to fit my needs?

Tags: command-line, sudo

I am attempting to force `powertop` to run when I log in by using the Startup Applications wizard in Ubuntu. Under the 'Command' entry, I've placed `gnome-terminal -x /home/***/Documents/programming/scripts/powertop.sh`. It's using a one-line bash shell script:

```
echo "******" | sudo -S powertop
```

This inputs my superuser password correctly but doesn't allow me to interact with powertop after it's initialized because it's continuously running echo.

How can I get privileges to run powertop using a shell script, yet still be able to use it in gnome-terminal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your powertop is in `/usr/sbin`, you can use `sudo /usr/sbin/powertop` with no password. To do this you need to run `visudo` and append the followind line, substituting `yourusername` with the real one:

```
yourusername ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/powertop
```

Comment: This works! (And thankfully, I can avoid the security issue of storing my password in a shell script...)

Comment: @user15008 If this is the right answer can you [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/145982)?

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten